# vue.js - Change text based on default/clicked class

Tags: vue.js

Given the following:

```
<div id="#my-container">
    <div class="title">Companies</div>

    <div class="tab active tab-apple">Apple</div>
    <div class="tab tab-google">Google</div>
</div>
```

1. When page is loaded without any tab clicks yet, whichever tab with the default active class, needs to go in the `.title` div. For the example above, `<div class="title">Apple</div>`
2. On click of a tab, the class is switched to active, and vue.js needs to update the `.title` div once again.

How can this be done with vue.js? I've tried but not able to get it to work as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer by David is one way to do it. But Vuejs offers in-line computations for this. So, no need to hook into any CSS event. Here's some code to explain:

Create a data property `active_tab`, just like David mentioned. And then bind it's value just like he's done it. In your tabs, add an click event and at that event, assign appropriate value to `active_tab`.

```
<div class="tab active tab-apple" @click="active_tab = Apple">Apple</div>
<div class="tab tab-google" @click="active_tab = Google">Google</div>
```

Now, to dynamically assign the active class to the respective tab, make the class attribute, a computed property, like this:

```
<div 
    :class="['tab', active_tab == 'Apple' ? 'active' : '', 'tab-apple']"
>
    Apple
</div>
```

What this code is basically doing is, `:class` makes class a computed property. Then the commas in the array divide the statement. So, the computation will always add `tab` and `tab-apple` classes. But, only  `if active_tab == 'Apple'` then `?` add `'active'` else `:` add `''`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure which CSS framework you are using, but normally I hook into the events thrown by the tab switching (many CSS frameworks provide this access). Once hooked into it, you can write a Vue custom directive that will take that event and use it to update a VM attribute that indicates which tab is active.

Then you can use normal mustache templating to get it into your template:

```
<div class="title">{{ active_tab }}</div>
```